# Rendering a partial to an edit form inside a popover in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Hi guys I really need help here.
I'm making a todo app and displaying each task through an iteration. Next to each task I have a pencil glyphicon.

When I click on it, I want there to be a popover containing an edit form and edit the task on the spot.  I'm having a ton of troubling rendering that form. 
***** UPDATE *****
Clark helped me get the popover to work.  But The form inside the popover is acting like a link instead of a form so I can't type in the text area.

This is my index.html.erb

```
    <div id='user_tasks'>
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <ul>
        <li>
        <%= task.description %>
      <%= link_to edit_task_path(task), :rel => 'popover', method: 'get', remote: 'true' do %> 
      <span class = 'edit_task_<%=task.id%> glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'> </span>
      <% end %>
        </li>
    </ul>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

This is the edit.js.erb

```
     $(function(){
         $('.edit_task_<%=@task.id%>').popover({
         html: true,
         title: 'edit',
         content: <%= escape_javascript render 'edit_form', task:@task %> 
           }).popover('show'); });
```

and my controllers look like this:

```
  def index
    @new_task= Task.new
    @tasks= Task.all    
  end

  def create
    @new_task= Task.new(task_params)
    @task.save
    redirect_to :back   
  end

  def edit
    @task= Task.find(params[:id])   
  end
```

_edit_form.html.erb looks like this: This isn't the edit form that I plan to use.  Its just a copy of the create task form.  I plan to fix it once I get the popover working.

```
    <%= form_for task, :html=>{:class=> 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: 'create a task' %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'submit', class:"btn btn-default btn-xs") do %>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is it currently doing, any errors? Also, use `content: <%= escape_javascript render 'edit_form' %> ` instead of `content: <%= render 'edit_form' %>`

Comment: Its not doing anything.  I don't see any errors.  I also updated the code to: `content: <%= escape_javascript render 'edit_form', task: @task %>`

Comment: Check your server log, when you click an icon do you see something like `Started GET "/task/id/edit" for etc..`<newline> `Processing by TaskController#edit as JS`<newline> `rendered task/edit.js` ? Or is there something else.

Comment: I got this `Rendered tasks/_edit_form.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered tasks/edit.js.erb (6764.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6768ms (Views: 6767.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/tasks/25/edit" for ::1 at 2015-05-27 16:49:52 -0400
Processing by TasksController#edit as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"25"}
  Task Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
  Rendered tasks/_edit_form.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered tasks/edit.js.erb (5.5ms)`

Comment: Okay, that's good. That means you have no ruby/routing errors. Your server is sending the right thing. This means it is likely something with the javascript.

Comment: When I replace the render the a string the popover appears. So I think youre right. But also when I hover over the popover, it's actually acting as it's own link...

Comment: Try `content: '<%= escape_javascript render 'edit_form', task: @task %>'`, I think having the quotes around the erb code is all you need.

Comment: Hey it worked! But the form isn't acting like a form now lol.

Comment: That's great, almost there. Now what do you mean it isn't acting like a form?

Comment: It doesn't let me type in the text area.  The form itself is a link.  So maybe there's something wrong with my erb code

Comment: That may be something with popover configuration, I'll admit I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Thanks man.  You got me 50% there!